# Two cover pages (titles) to a thesis document, in different languages

Tags: titles, thesis, sharelatex, covers

I'm using the [Princeton-university-thesis tamplate](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/princeton-university-thesis). I need to create a cover page in English and anther one in Hebrew.
How this is can be made with the template I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title page is created by `\maketitlepage`. If you look in the class file `puthesis.cls` you will find the definition of this macro. What I suggest you do is copy this, as below, and modify it as appropriate for your second title page (as you don't give the details it is hard to do this for you!).

I am not sure whether you want to print both title pages in the document or be able to print different title pages for different versions. Assuming that you want to print both once you have defined `\makehebrewtitlepage` below in your thesis you can type:

```
\maketitlepage
\makehebrewtitlepage
```

Here is a start toward defining `\makehebrewtitlepage`. I have highlighted where you need to make changes.

```
\newcommand{\makehebrewtitlepage}{{
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \sc
  \vspace*{0in}
  \begin{center}
    \LARGE <insert Hebrew title>
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.6in}
  \extravspace{.6in}
  \begin{center}
    \@author% replace with your name in Hebrew
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.6in}
  \extravspace{.6in}
  \begin{center}
    A Dissertation \\    % translate this
    Presented to the Faculty \\
    of Princeton University \\
    in Candidacy for the Degree \\
    of Doctor of Philosophy
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.3in}
  \extravspace{.3in}
  \begin{center}
    Recommended for Acceptance \\ % translate this
    by the \@deptpref \\
    \@dept \\
    Adviser: \@adviser
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.3in}
  \extravspace{.3in}
  \begin{center}
    \@submitted
  \end{center}
  \clearpage
  }}
```